# Error is Sql syntax

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting SQL syntax error in the following code snippet. What is the problem here? I am unable to figure it out. Please help.

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM cost_info where `date` > ? and `date` < ?  order by `date`";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);

        java.sql.Date sqlFromDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(from_date);
        java.sql.Date sqlEndDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(end_date);

        preparedStatement.setDate(1, sqlFromDate );
        preparedStatement.setDate(2, sqlEndDate );
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

I am using MySQL. Error is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and `date` < ?  order by `date`' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2569)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1521)
at com.source.viralmo.rms.CostDisplay.initialize(CostDisplay.java:77)
at com.source.viralmo.rms.CostDisplay.<init>(CostDisplay.java:34)
at com.source.viralmo.rms.AdminPage.actionPerformed(AdminPage.java:141)
```

Comment: What database are you using, and what exactly does the error message say?

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and press `{}`. And use the preview to see what your post will look like.

Comment: Better formatted now. Please suggest some solutions. Apparently, order by clause was just one of the problem here. Anything else you guys can think of ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `order by` should go after `where`.

Second, if you are using MySQL, `date` should be quoted since it's a reserved word for the `DATE` type. The query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM cost_info where `date` > ? and `date` < ?  order by `date`
```

Third, prepared statements are executed with the `executeQuery()` method. The `executeQuery(String)` method that is being used here is for executing normal statements; for example it doesn't substitute parameters so the `?` is passed as-is to the database. You need:

```
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(/* empty */);
```

Comment: It does not seem to be the only problem.

Comment: Yes indeed this is the answer. Tried everything in my case: Changing columntypes between DATETIME, DATE and TIMESTAMP, using all the PreparedStatement set-methods. I nearly gave up. Saw your answer and inserted my cleverly named columns 'from' and 'to' into a MySQL Workbench code-editor and saw them changing to blue. Yikes. From. I wish mysql could be more like Captain Obvious in such moments. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM cost_info order by date where date > ? and date < ?
```

you have placed `order by` in wrong place, it should be at last of the query.

```
SELECT * FROM cost_info where date > ? and date < ?  order by date
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by clause comes after where clause

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM cost_info where date > ? and date < ?  order by date` is the right sql in your case